# Getting a value of a disabled HTML checkbox using Request.Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

I have a html checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MyChkBox" .. />
```

There is another control that makes this enable/disabled and I am doing that using JQuery

```
$(this).attr("disabled", "true");
```

On the server, I get the checkbox values using:

```
string info = Request.Form["MyChkBox"];
```

My problem is if a checkbox is checked and disabled, I need to be able to get this value using `Request.Form`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this, you'll need to re-enable it to see/get it server-side (otherwise the client won't send it at all).  The browser doesn't  include `disabled` controls in the `<form>` submission, [since they don't count as "successful" controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

Answer (score 1):

You could have the checkboxes there for display purposes, and have some hidden fields that contain the actual values that are passed to the server.

If the checkboxes ever need to become enabled on the client-side, you can have them change the value of the hidden element `onchange`, so that the values match.